# How do I do convert a relational data model into a NoSQL document store type data model?

Tags: database, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I'm developing an attendance taking application where `students` can scan a barcode to verify attendance. At the most basic level, I have thought of creating `students`, `classes`, and `attendance` tables. `students` and `classes` will have a many-to-many relationship which is why I introduce the `attendance` table.

For my use case, I'm thinking of generating a new barcode every day of the class, for each class. I'm using Firebase for this project and this is my first experience with a NoSQL database which is why I'm having a difficult time modeling this type of relationship. I'd appreciate your inputs on the possible ways how my database should look like.

Comment: Watch this series > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o

Comment: @GastónSaillén Thanks! Going through it right now.